# python libraries for programatic email access: mime, smtp, pop3

Tags: python, email, pop3

Does python have built in libraries for accessing email including: smtp, pop3, mime parsers etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely:

- [smtplib — SMTP protocol client](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html)
- [poplib — POP3 protocol client](http://docs.python.org/library/poplib.html)
- [imaplib — IMAP4 protocol client](http://docs.python.org/library/imaplib.html)
- [email — An email and MIME handling package](http://docs.python.org/library/email)

They are all included in the Python standard library.

Comment: Python also has excellent documentation at http://docs.python.org including the Library Reference which includes all the above and much more.